# Preload data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, preloading

I have some big data (dictionaries, index etc) which take a long time to load. So how i can once preload these data and then use in every request to my site(ofcourse without loading)?

Comment: What is the data source?

Answer (score 0):

The question is too abstract, however if memory is not a constraint, then you might think off preloading the data in static objects of equivalent data structure during application_start() execution. However, ensure to reload the data , if it gets changed. Observer design pattern or similar may be handy for these scenario.